# The "Display a Map" example isn't displaying any map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/simple-map/

My code is as follows, just as in the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Display a map</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MY_TOKEN';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/ericgithinji/ckfchv1sr0u581amw703zg3jh',//it also fails when I use one of the public styles
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The div for the map doesn't display anyting, i.e. I get a blank web page. I've followed the tests here for style_id, tileset id, and access token and they all work: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/blank-tiles/

I have no idea what could be the problem. If it helps,my Index.html is hosted locally on Ubuntu Apache2 server.

Answer (score 1):

I was making two mistakes: 1 - using my secret token instead of my public token and 2 - not generating a style for myself first (it didn't work with the default style from the example).