# why am i getting blank page on mapboxgl React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using React to build a map component, setup looks good considering I followed the example by the Mapbox team [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/) and [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-react-examples/blob/master/basic/src/Map.js)

But I get a blank page when the component mounts, I have seen a series of similar issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71014226/why-i-am-getting-a-blank-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992555/the-display-a-map-example-isnt-displaying-any-map) none seem to solve my problem.

[image]

see my code sample

```
import mapboxgl from '!mapbox-gl'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-webpack-loader-syntax
import { Box } from '@mui/system';

import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import '../components/propertyMap.css';

const PropertyMap = () => {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
     
  const [property_id, setProperty_id] = useState('');

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setProperty_id(e.target.value);
  };

  mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mapboxgl.supported()) {
      alert('Your browser does not support Mapbox GL');
    }
    if (map.current) return;
    map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: 'mapbox styles here',
      center: [6.459964, 7.548949],
      zoom: 14,
      attributionControl: true,
      interactive: true,
      customAttribution: '&copy',
      boxZoom: true,
    });

    map.current.setCenter([6.459964, 7.548949]);

    // mapboxgl.boxZoomCursor = 'grab';
    map.current.boxZoom.enable();
    map.current.addControl(
      new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(),
      'top-right'
    );
    map.current.addControl(
      new mapboxgl.AttributionControl({ compact: true })
    );
    map.current.resize();
    return () => map.current.remove();
  }, [property]);

  return (
      <Box>
        <Box ref={mapContainer} className='mapContainer' />
      </Box>
  );
};

export default PropertyMap;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it to display

changed the map ref from map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({ });

to

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({ });

and it worked.